# ssh twice in one go, using netcat

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, netcat

I am in this situation where I want to connect to a computer in my uni's network, and I have to hop through a server which has access to the uni's network.

So this command works fine:

```
ssh -t user@serverAdress ssh user@uniPCAdress
```

But since I rely a lot on scp command, I was looking for a better option.

I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311447/how-do-i-ssh-to-machine-a-via-b-in-one-command#) which was about the same issue and ran this command:

```
$ ssh username@serverAdress nc uniPCAdress

    SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
```

I receive this random output, then the command stops after running for a few seconds.

And since I am here, I would like to ask how to specify a username for the uniPCAdress? For my case it doesn't matter because the usernames are the same, but that would be useful knowledge.

Comment: You should read about the ssh `ProxyJump` configuration option, which is a much simpler solution to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to Server Fault...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

As larsks mentionned, ProxyJump was indeed a much better option!

```
Host uniViaServer
HostName uniPC
User username
ProxyJump username@server
```